# How to refer to the original object from which a model is created

Tags: word-choice

If I have, for example, a model ship, model railroad, model car, etc. what is the best word to refer to the original from what this model is created?

I'm also looking for a context-free version, to use it in a heading and the table of contents, this is why I'm looking for an alternative for "model" or "prototype".

Comment: You used the word in your question: the "original".

Comment: Yes, but that can have a lot of meanings. Is there something that expresses that it is the "example" for the model? Like in the German word "Vorbild"?

Comment: I would think that most of the time the meaning of "original" is fairly clear from context. In the cases where it's not, you would make it clear by saying "the original for this model", "the original ship", or something similar.

Comment: Part of the difficulty is that 'model' is what you call a person who stands still to be copied in the artwork, which is contrary to the meaning for a model ship.

Comment: Many, many (most?) English words have multiple meanings. Don't be afraid to use them anyway, but make sure the context makes the meaning clear.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Prototype* has the exact meaning you are looking for, although you must be careful because in common usage it also means an experimental version upon which a more polished version can be based.

If you can clear up the difference using context, then *prototype* is fine:

> The HMS Victory is the prototype for this scale model.

vs

> I wasn't sure the mechanism would work, so I made a prototype from scrap wood first.

You could also use *archetype*, *precedent*, *blueprint* or simply *original*.

Do look up all of these words in the dictionary, for the fine detail of their various meanings; there are subtle differences.

Comment: This was exactly my problem: I was suggested using "prototype", but dismissed it as I thought it can only mean the experimental version. Wikipedia only strengthened my suspicions.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype: 'In the field of scale modeling (which includes model railroading, vehicle modeling, airplane modeling, military modeling, etc.), a prototype is the real-world basis or source for a scale model...' However, this usage is confined to the Scale Modeling domain.

Comment: I think the more usual phrase would be "The HMS Victory is the original for this scale model," which is also made perfectly clear from context. But from Google, I see *prototype* is also used for this.

Comment: Unless you are addressing people from the field of Scale Modeling specifically, you must steer clear of this term.

Comment: *prototype* is just a little more literate. Note also, in some programming languages and software design patterns "prototype" is used to refer to a chunk of data that's made to be cloned.

Comment: "Blueprint" is generally understood to mean the plans or diagrams from which something is built, not another physical object that it is based on. I see this listed as definition #4 on thefreedictionary.com, but I think that's a pretty rare usage and should be used carefully.

Comment: "Archetype" is technically correct but it is usually understood to mean an ideal or standard, rather than any object used as an original. Thus we might say, "HMS Dreadnaught was the archetype for all battleships for the next 50 years." So if you said that a certain object was the archetype for your scale model, depending on context people might think you meant that you used it as a conceptual ideal rather than you patterned your model after it in detail.

Comment: Actually I'm going to be more bullish. A *prototype* is the basis for copies or derivative works, whether it was built for that purpose or not. Whether I base my model on HMS Victory, or on a makeshift model, that basis can always be referred to as a prototype. Also applies in more abstract concepts such as philosophy. Google "the prototype for".

Comment: @slim: You did suggest *prototype* as well as *original*, so where's the issue? :)

Comment: @Kris the issue is that a few people are suggesting that "original" is better. "Prototype" is more precise, and therefore better for me. I'm all for people using more precise words when they're available.

Comment: @jay Google "the blueprint for"; nowadays it is more frequently used to refer to an, er, prototype than it is to plans on paper. It's one of those metaphors which is so frequently used that people forget the original definition.

Comment: RE prototype: IMHO, the word is most often understood to mean an experimental version, so any other use is potentially confusing. In the proper context, or with a sentence of explanation, it might be a better choice. But I wouldn't use it in this sense for a one-shot remark to a general audience.

Comment: @slim I just did a Yahoo search on "blueprint". Of the first 40 results, 18 clearly used the word to describe a document, either literal construction plans or some other sort of written plan ("the Obama administration's blueprint for education reform ...", etc), 2 clearly referred to a prototype (one being a movie about a person who is cloned), and the remaining 20 not being immediately clear (an iPad app and a musical group by that name, etc) Of course this is purely anecdotal, but I think the word "blueprint" still means "written or printed plan" to most people.

Answer (score 4):

If you are specifically addressing people from the field of Scale Modeling, who are expected to be familiar with the special import of the word, you may use *prototype*.

For the general public, you would better refer to it as the *original*.

Answer (score 4):

As Peter says, I think "original" is the best word in general for this idea.

In one of those curious twists of the English language, "model" is another commonly-used term. Thus one might say, "Sally Jones was the model for this sculpture" or "I used the HMS Victory as the model for a toy boat that I made." But then we have the catch that "model" is also used to mean the copy! It would be perfectly accurate to say, "I used HMS Victory as the model for my scale model" -- perfectly accurate but very confusing! And then if you tried to explain differences between the original and the replica, would you say, "The model was made of wood but the model is made of plastic", etc?

Answer (score 2):

There are several words which would do.

According to [Wordnet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&s=original), **original**, **archetype**, and **pilot** can all be used in the sense of *something that serves as a model or a basis for making copies*. **Pilot** won't work; it's normally used when a small scale model is created before the full scale vehicle, but you're interested in the opposite circumstance.

[Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) offers **model**, **example**, and **paragon** as translations of the German word *Vorbild* you asked about in your comment. **Paragon** means a *perfect* example of something, and you are not looking for a word with that limited sense.

Here are some sentences about model trains which use **original**, **archetype**, **model**, and **example** to mean *something that serves as a model or a basis for making copies*. Note that *model* can mean either the the original or the copy.

- Pictured is a 1:8 scale replica of the **original** locomotive designed by Matthias N. Forney.
- The **archetype** for today's modern model trains is the Birmingham Dribbler.
- The **model** for this electric train is the "Train Eclair de luxe": the first Orient Express.
- This HO gauge caboose is an **example** of the typical crew cabin of the 1970's.